# argparse like docker cli

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Hello i am writing cmd tool,
i want to have behaviour like docker does:

`docker container run --help`

print the help for this particular command.
im stucked with code:

`parser.add_argument("method", help=getHelp())`

but the method can be anything like

- add
- remove
- update

and how to later add a method in add like:

- add ram
- add cpu

i can add subparser for add but how to add later a subparser for ram ?
How can i achieve that with argparse in python?

Is it even possible?

Can somebody show me example of third deep command with its own arguments ?

Comment: Subparsers can have their own  subparsers.

Comment: I created solution gonna post It tomoorow

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse
import pprint
import random


def get_comments(args):
    return [{'post_id': args.post_id,
             'comment_id': str(random.randrange(1, 1000)),
             'comment': "< comment's body >"}
            for _ in range(random.randrange(1, 10))]


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')

list_parser = subparsers.add_parser('list')

list_subparsers = list_parser.add_subparsers(dest='type')
comments_parser = list_subparsers.add_parser('comments')
comments_parser.add_argument('post_id')
comments_parser.set_defaults(func=get_comments)

accounts_parser = list_subparsers.add_parser('accounts')

show_parser = subparsers.add_parser('show')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
print(args.command)
#result = args.func(args)
print(parser)
#pprint.pprint(args)
```

Comment: This solves and with that you can create multi subcommands in cli